# check if a lua function is anonymous?

Tags: lua

I register callback as event handler in my game, like this:

```
--register event handler
EventDispatcher:register("fire", mt.onPlayerFire, self)


--this is the event handler
mt:onPlayerFire()
    print("play fire")
end

--unregister event handler
EventDispachter:unregister("fire", mt.onPlayerFire, self)
```

When the event handler is a function in module `mt`, it is fine to unregister it, because I can find the same function in `mt` to unregister it, but when I use this form:

```
EventDispatcher:register("fire", function() doSomething() end, nil)
```

I could not unregister the event handler, because it is anonymous, so I want to add some checks in my `register` function to prevent anonymous function as the event handler.

I have found the Proto struct in lua source code may be helpful, but I do not know what each piece means.

https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lobject.h.html#Proto

Comment: You can introduce new function `unregister_last()` to be able to unregister last registered function without specifying it.  You registering system would remember stack of `register()` invocations and `unregister_last()` function would "pop" from this stack one function and unregister it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of avoids your question a bit, but it might solve your problem nonetheless.

When registering a new callback you could simply return some sort of identifying value, like an ID, a table or even the function itself. This could allow you to unregister it at a later moment.

```
local firehandler = EventDispatcher:register("fire", function() do('something') end)
-- Do some stuff here...
EventDispatcher:unregister(firehandler)
```

The downside is that you may have to change the way your event dispatcher keeps track of its registered events, but at worst this means implementing some linked list, and at best you can just use a Lua table to keep track of your handlers.

As for detecting anonymous functions, that's not really possible. Lua doesn't distinguish a function you define in-place from one stored in a variable; it's ultimately the same thing.

It might be possible by using the `debug` library, by comparing the file/line where a function is defined with the call stack, but that's just inviting bugs into your code and would probably be rather slow.

Comment: I use a array to track all event handler for a specific event, and return the array index where the handler is stored, but the issue is when I unregister previous handler, the array  shifts down others, make the previous returned index invalid. So I guess I should not use array to store my handlers, any further suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

> I could not unregister the event handler, because it is anonymouse

Every function in Lua is anonymous value. So you can't unregister not because it is anonymous but because you didn't save any reference to it.

There is no way to detect inside of `EventDispatcher:register()` if the passed value (of `function` type) is also saved elsewhere. So if you really have multiple callbacks for the same event, and you want to unregister one specific callback, then you must have a way to identify that exact callback function.

That means you should either save the function value somewhere, so its own value could be used later as identifier for `unregister()`, as it is now, or return new callback's instance id, generated inside of `register()` when callback was added. Either way, there's something to be stored outside of `EventDispatcher` to identify exact callback.